# Recommended size for full screen bg image?

Tags: css, image, background, viewport

What is the recommended size (pixel dimensions and / or file size) for full screen (desktop) background images considering that some monitors like the iMac are 5K.

I'm thinking in broad terms and more for load time considerations.

Should I detect viewport and load different sized images for different viewports?

Comment: That depends on so many factors. "Is the image blurred" springs to mind. With blurred images, you can get away with much smaller ones. But there are so many facets to this issue, it's really impossible to give an impartial answer.

Comment: add you sample code with css

Comment: I'm speaking in broad terms and more for load time consideration. A 6,000 x 4,000 bg image, blurred or not, is likely to be pretty large.